# The wp_blogmeta table is not installed. Please run the network database upgrade

Tags: multisite

We’re using WP Engine for web hosting.

I originally manually turned on Multisite through `wp-config.php` & `Tools > Network Setup`.

Since then, I've learned we need to use their `Enable Multisite` function to enable subdirectory multisite.

When `WP_DEBUG` is on, we see a message:

> Notice: wp_check_site_meta_support_prefilter was called incorrectly. The wp_blogmeta table is not installed. Please run the network database upgrade.

I then created `wp_blogmeta` manually using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_blogmeta (
meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
blog_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘0’,
meta_key varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
meta_value longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (meta_id),
KEY meta_key (meta_key(191)),
KEY blog_id (blog_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

If I run the network database upgrade, the error remains.

How do I populate/”install” this table?

**EDIT**: WP Engine say they do not support issues with Multisite, so they're unable to help me resolve this.

Our `wp-config.php` contains:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/'); 
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', ''); 
define('COOKIEPATH', ''); 
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

We're using `WordPress 6.0`.

Comment: You will probably need to check with WP Engine support.

Comment: @PatJ, I've edited my question. I originally manually set up MU the normal way, and later learned I needed to use their official process.

Comment: If WP Engine has special instructions for setting up Multisite, you're almost certainly going to need help from their support team to solve this.

Comment: @Steve if you have not already checked it, https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-creating-table-wp-blogmeta/page/2/#post-11265255 (or other replies there) might help. But if I were you, I'd contact the WP Engine (tech) support team and ask for their assistance in resolving the issue in question.

Comment: @PatJ, WP Engine say they do not support MU issues.

Comment: @SallyCJ, WP Engine say they do not support MU issues.

Comment: That's unfortunate, @Steve. And what I can suggest now, is 1) Clear all your caches, then disable Multisite and enable it back *using WP Engine's [automated process](https://wpengine.com/support/what-is-wordpress-multisite/)*, 2) Install WordPress in a new blank directory, then enable Multisite, also using that automated process. If none helps, then you should probably just hire someone to do it for you, if WP Engine is also not offering a service to do that for you (even if you're gonna pay?).

Answer (score 2):

This was an error on an older version of WordPress, version 5.1 ([Core Issue #46167](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46167)). Do you use the last stable version of WordPress?

But try the following options to solve the problem.

## Install again, Core or WP CLI

Copy all files from the core again in your installation, like via sFTP, especially all files in the directories `wp-inlcudes` and `wp-admin`. Run the installation again. Alternate if you have the possibility with the usage of [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/)  `wp core update-db --network`.

## Upgrade again

Go in your installation to the URL `wp-admin/network/upgrade.php` and perform the upgrade again.

## Manual

Create the table or check your manual steps for this creation

```sql
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->blogmeta (
    meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    blog_id bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
    meta_key varchar(255) default NULL,
    meta_value longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id),
    KEY meta_key (meta_key($max_index_length)),
    KEY blog_id (blog_id)
) $charset_collate;
```

Now look at the table `wp_sitemeta`, field `site_meta_supported` and set the value to 1. Background is, WP looks via `is_site_meta_supported()` for this value to use the table.

Comment: Thanks. The table `wp_sitemeta` is empty after I created it. What row do I need to insert, please?

Comment: That should not be an option, because it is to depend on your installation, settings, plugins and themes, user etc.. So try the reinstallation process.

Comment: I've done so, error remains.

Comment: Which version of WP do you use? Reinstallation of all core files are done? Provide also your wp-config.php in the question, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: We're using WP 6.0. Reinstallation of core files is done. `wp-config.php` added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed I was only getting the error for certain subsites.  I had run the Network Upgrade successfully multiple times, but when I went directly to the subsite upgrade page like at `mysite.com/subsites/wp-admin/upgrade.php`
and then ran the database upgrade that made the errors go away for me. (I had to do that for each subsite that was creating errors)

I also still do not have a `wp_blogmeta` table, but no more errors.

This was running wp version 5.9.3.

Comment: I received a message `No Update Required` when I tried that

Answer (score 1):

The URL to access the network database update is

https://www.website.test/wp-admin/network/upgrade.php

Or the location to where `/wp-admin/` is installed plus `/network/upgrade.php`- as commenters have mentioned - I would reach out to WP Engine though - as you may have done something unexpected by adding those tables yourself.

Now might be a good time to check your backup processes have been working correctly too :-)

Comment: "If I run the network database upgrade, the error remains."

Comment: Ah... my apologies RTFQ

Comment: i tried all of the steps from the answers, but setting the field in `wp_sitemeta` was the only thing that worked for an install with 4 subsites. https://gist.github.com/Sandra-headscape/6354792805a6e6cca3179f532d1c4bbf

Comment: Nice, that worked for me.